# WIN API ReadFile() returns GetLastError() ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, winapi

I wrote this code below and it worked fine under code::blocks using mingw gcc 4.7 to compile it. I have since decided to start using Visual Studio 2013 express. Now I am getting an error when ReadFile() is called. Which seems to be an invalid parameter. I can't see the error hoping someone here can spot it.

This is all wrapped inside a class Serial. From what I can see in the IDE the memory reference for m_hSerial is correct when compared to the reference CreateFile() returns to the handle.

```
m_hSerial = CreateFile(m_pchPort,
                       GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                       0,
                       0,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                       0);
```

I call the WorkThread like so

```
m_hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &WorkThread, (void*) this, 0, 0);
```

Here is the WorkThread code

```
unsigned int __stdcall Serial::WorkThread(void* pvParam)
{
// This is a pointer to the 'this' serial class.
// Needed to be able to set members of the class in a static class function
Serial * cThis = (Serial*) pvParam;
// Set up the overlapped event
OVERLAPPED ov;
memset(&ov, 0, sizeof(ov));
ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, true, 0, 0);
DWORD dwEventMask = 0;
DWORD dwWait;
HANDLE aHandles[2];
aHandles[0] = cThis->m_hThreadTerminator;
aHandles[1] = ov.hEvent;

SetEvent(cThis->m_hThreadRunning);
while (true)
{
    if (!WaitCommEvent(cThis->m_hSerial, &dwEventMask, &ov))
    {
        assert(GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING);

    }

    dwWait = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, aHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);
    switch(dwWait)
    {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        {
            _endthreadex(1);
        }
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
        {
            if (dwEventMask & EV_TXEMPTY)
            {
                ResetEvent(ov.hEvent);
            }
            else if (dwEventMask & EV_RXCHAR)
            {
                // read data here
                DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
                DWORD dwErrors;
                COMSTAT cStat;
                OVERLAPPED ovRead;
                ovRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, true, 0, 0);

                // Get the Bytes in queue
                ClearCommError(cThis->m_hSerial, &dwErrors, &cStat);
                DWORD nSize = cStat.cbInQue;
                // EM_REPLACESEL needs a LPARAM null terminated string, make room and set the CString NULL
                char *szBuf = new char[nSize+1];
                memset(szBuf, 0x00, sizeof(szBuf));

                if (!ReadFile(cThis->m_hSerial, &szBuf, nSize, &dwBytesRead, &ovRead))
                    DWORD err = GetLastError();
                if (dwBytesRead == nSize)
                    SendMessage(cThis->m_hHwnd, WM_SERIAL, 0, LPARAM(&szBuf));

                CloseHandle(ovRead.hEvent); // clean up!!!
                delete[] szBuf;
            }
            // Reset the overlapped event
            ResetEvent(ov.hEvent);
        }
        break;
    }//switch
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why do you dereference `szBuf` when calling `ReadFile()`? By passing szBuf directly you implicitly do `&szBuf[0]` which should be the correct approach to call this function.

Comment: You forgot to properly initialize ovRead, use `OVERLAPPED ovRead = {};`

Comment: @HansPassant you were correct, that was my error. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You can ask David to update his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ReadFile(cThis->m_hSerial, &szBuf, nSize, &dwBytesRead, &ovRead)
```

You are asking for an asynchronous operation, but also asking the function to tell you how many bytes have been read. You passed `&dwBytesRead` as the penultimate parameter. When you are performing overlapped reading, pass `NULL` for this parameter. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) says:

> Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results.

It is also a mistake to pass `&szBuf` in the code above. You mean to pass `szBuf`.

You also fail to initialize the `OVERLAPPED` struct. Do so like this:

```
OVERLAPPED ovRead = {};
```

A bigger problem is that you ask for asynchronous access, but then write the code as it it were synchronous. As soon as `ReadFile` returns you attempt to get meaningful information out of `dwBytesRead` and you close the event that you put in the overlapped struct.

If you are really going code this asynchronously, you need to re-write the code to be asynchronous. On the face of it, it looks as though you have not fully understood the implications of overlapped I/O and you should perhaps switch to non-overlapped, synchronous I/O.

Comment: You mean to pass `&szBuf[0]` *

Comment: @Vinzenz Silly typo, `szBuf` is what I meant, now fixed, thanks

Comment: yes, but you wrote `&szBuf` instead of `szBuf`. Also its just a language thing. In the end `szBuf` and `&szBuf[0]` are the same ;)

Comment: There is no "must", it is only a recommendation.

Comment: I agree, I have probably not understood it fully. But that is the end means. Thanks for the quick response, I will look into changing the code.

Comment: @Vinzenz I made a mistake. I wrote something I did not intend to do. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: @HansPassant The documentation says *Use NULL for this parameter if this is an asynchronous operation to avoid potentially erroneous results.* which leaves little room for manoeuvre in my view.